# Linked List Thread safe?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Well i writing in .net and i have a list to witch i will only add item never remove and its a linked list i can change that if its not the best pick but any way to the point would it be safe to not use any locking in this case when i know that this list will never be changed in any other manner but that its added to? (a lock will be used when trying to add to the list)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it is not safe.  LinkedList is not a thread safe class.  The only supported multi-thread scenario for LinkedList is multiple readers

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7.aspx

Comment: well thats what im trying to say sorry if i did write it a bit miss leading, many readers and only one writer... would that be safe, or atleast only one writer at the time.

Comment: @Petoj - reading would not be safe concurrently with a writer - even if the write is limited to a single thread.

Answer (score 6):

No; to support many readers and one writer (comments to Jared's reply), you might want to look at `ReaderWriterLockSlim`. The writer requires exclusive access; the readers can co-operate. This is what `ReaderWriterLockSlim` does. There is also `ReaderWriterLock` pre 3.5.

You will need to handle enter/exit etc manually - ideally via try/finally.